# How many classes can CNN classify the short text?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I know that CNN(conv-neural-network) could classify more than 10 thousands of images of the ImageNet.

I find that CNN could only classify 10-20 text classes as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01710.pdf) write.

How many classes can CNN classify the short text? **What is the high limit of the classes number?**

Comment: What is CNN and what context does it really hold to your question?  This reads very confusingly.

Comment: @Makoto I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of categories a classifier could classify with good precision/recall is decided by (but not limited to):

- how distinct each category is?
- how many features you could derive from the content (short text definitely carries much less information here than images) -- since you are using CNN for text, I assume the features would be merely characters or words.
- How these features work to differentiate between categories?
- how many high-quality labeled examples you have? (We don't have a public labeled large multi-category dataset for short text)

It's hard to just give you a number without knowing the answers to above questions.